# Does 自分も imply 自分もしなければ in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> 死者とは過去だ。骸を弔ってやる以外に何もしてやれない、過去の残影。
>
> それに囚われたまま未来を見るのは、……きっと酷く、難しいことなのだろうけれど。
>
> 「……ていうか。連邦に来る前に最後に戦闘になった時も、今から思えば変だったよね。ああいうことは、……絶対死ぬってわかってるのに行くような真似は、**自分も他の奴にもさせなかったのに**」
>
> それまでは、兄の亡霊を討たねばならなかったから。
>
> そのために、生き延びなければならなかったから。

86─エイティシックス─Ep.3 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈下〉
安里アサト

According to a source, the  fourth sentence translates as "…Anyway, that last battle we had before we arrived at the Federation seemed weird now that I think about it…it's like he was so willing to do it even after knowing that he'll die. Back then, he would never do that, nor let anyone else do it."

I don’t understand where “he would never do that” comes from. Does 自分も imply that? For that meaning, shouldn’t the sentence be 自分もしなければ他の奴にもさせなかったのに?

Comment: 自分もしなかったし is more likely. しなければ sounds a bit stilted.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are right in that the original sentence is wrong, strictly speaking. But by context the translation is likely to be correct.

Also, 自分もしなければ他の奴にもさせなかったのに is one possibility for correction as you guessed. Another would be 自分**に**もほかのやつにも... = *didn't let himself nor others do (such a thing)*.